# JQuery - Como usar um link href para chamar uma dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

Preciso de um comando que abra uma dialog toda vez que clicar em um link...

```
    <map name="Mapeamento">
    <div id="dialog" title="Imagem1">
            <p>Informação 1</p>
            <p>Informação 2</p>
            </div>
            <script>
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false});
            </script> <area shape="poly" coords="1020,240,1000,225,1020,210,1040,215" href="ABRIR A DIALOG APARTIR DAQUI">
```

Tentei coisas como: *href="Imagem1"*, por exemplo, mas nada funcionou.

Tenho que usar o comando href por estar utilizando a função de mapeamento de imagem. Já procurei em muitos lugares, mas nenhum dizia como tranformar uma área determinada por *area shape* em um link que abra uma caixa de diálogo...
Obrigada desde já!

Comment: E cada link deve ter um comportamento diferente ou simplesmente abrir o mesmo dialog com o mesmo conteúdo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, todas as posições usam uma dialog, mas elas serão diferentes...

Comment: Usam todos o mesmo dialog `#dialog`?

Comment: Não, podem ser #dialogImagem1, por exemplo.

Comment: E de onde vem essa informação de cada conteúdo?

Comment: vem de uma div: <div id="dialog" title="Imagem1">
            <p>Informação 1</p>
            <p>Informação 2</p>
            </div>    O código está funcionando bem, exibe a caixa certinho, mas ela aparece logo que eu atualizo a página, preciso que ela apareça quando a pessoa clicar nas coordendas

Comment: podes dar um exemplo de html com dois links e o conteudo/divs respetivas onde o modal deve ir buscar conteúdo?

Comment: <map name="Mapeamento">
    <div id="dialogExemplo1" title="Imagem1"> </div><script> $( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false});   <div id="dialogExemplo2" title="Imagem2"> <script>$( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false});</script>                        <area shape="poly" coords="1020,240,1000,225,1020,210,1040,215" href="ABRIR A DIALOGEXEMPLO1 APARTIR DAQUI">                    <area shape="poly" coords="870,530,820,530,885,474,890,500" href="ABIR DIALOGEXEMPLO2 APARTIR DAQUI" >

Answer (score 1):

**Troque true por false:**

`$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});`

**Apenas a visualizar como true:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: true});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<map name="Mapeamento">
  <div id="dialog" title="Imagem1">
    <p>Informação 1</p>
    <p>Informação 2</p>
  </div>
  <area shape="poly" coords="1020,240,1000,225,1020,210,1040,215" href="ABRIR A DIALOG APARTIR DAQUI">
```